# Why is gnome-mplayer stuttering?

Tags: gnome, xfce, video-player, mplayer

The stutter occurs at random when playing mp3 files.

It also occurs specifically when using space bar to pause/restart a running video. But it only occurs if that video has been fwd/rev using the arrow keys.

Here follows the error log created when running video, which shows output generated while mplayer did the following processes:

1. open a video file
2. play it
3. pause/restart three times with spacebar
4. fwd
5. pause/restart three times with spacebar

Error log:

```
GMLIB-Message: Running with GIO support
GMLIB-Message: Using audio device: 
GMLIB-Message: after init: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=0.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=
GMLIB-Message: failed to get mode: Error when getting information for file '/media/gringo/videos/options': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: opening options
GMLIB-Message: stat_result = -1
GMLIB-Message: is block false
GMLIB-Message: is character false
GMLIB-Message: is reg false
GMLIB-Message: is dir false
GMLIB-Message: playlist false
GMLIB-Message: embedded in window id 0x0
GMLIB-Message: playlist detection = false
GMLIB-Message: adding file:///media/gringo/videos/options to playlist (cancel = false)
GMLIB-Message: playlist detection = false
GMLIB-Message: adding file:///media/gringo/videos/filename to playlist (cancel = false)
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='com.gnome.mplayer'
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='org.gnome.SettingsDaemon'
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys'
GMLIB-Message: Proxy connections and Command connected
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2'
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player'
GMLIB-Message: Proxy connections and Command connected ret = 2
GMLIB-Message: playing - file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: is playlist false
GMLIB-Message: old: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: new: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: setting up mplayer
GMLIB-Message: mplayer -channels 2 -af-add export=/tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew:512 -quiet -slave -noidle -noconsolecontrols -nostop-xscreensaver -identify -volume 100 -softvol -msglevel all=5 -osdlevel 0 -delay 0 -subdelay 0 -subpos 0 -sub-fuzziness 0 -wid 0x3c00020 -brightness 0 -contrast 0 -hue 0 -saturation 0 -nomsgcolor -nomsgmodule -nokeepaspect -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-font-scale 1 /media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: launched: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: < MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Playing /media/gringo/videos/options.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/media/gringo/videos/options': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /media/gringo/videos/options.
GMLIB-Message: < Exiting... (End of file)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_EXIT=EOF
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 66 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 67 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 68 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: finished: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: playing - file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: is playlist false
GMLIB-Message: old: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: setting up mplayer
GMLIB-Message: new: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: mplayer -channels 2 -af-add export=/tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew:512 -quiet -slave -noidle -noconsolecontrols -nostop-xscreensaver -identify -volume 100 -softvol -msglevel all=5 -osdlevel 0 -delay 0 -subdelay 0 -subpos 0 -sub-fuzziness 0 -wid 0x3c00020 -brightness 0 -contrast 0 -hue 0 -saturation 0 -nomsgcolor -nomsgmodule -nokeepaspect -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-font-scale 1 /media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: launched: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: < MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Playing /media/gringo/videos/filename.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/media/gringo/videos/filename': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /media/gringo/videos/filename.
GMLIB-Message: < Exiting... (End of file)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_EXIT=EOF
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 86 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 87 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 88 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: finished: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 86 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 88 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 87 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 86 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 88 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 87 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: old: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: new: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: opening playlist
GMLIB-Message: playlist detection = false
GMLIB-Message: adding file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4 to playlist (cancel = false)
GMLIB-Message: playing - file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: is playlist false
GMLIB-Message: old: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: setting up mplayer
GMLIB-Message: mplayer -channels 2 -af-add export=/tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew:512 -quiet -slave -noidle -noconsolecontrols -nostop-xscreensaver -identify -volume 100 -softvol -msglevel all=5 -osdlevel 0 -delay 0 -subdelay 0 -subpos 0 -sub-fuzziness 0 -wid 0x3c00020 -brightness 0 -contrast 0 -hue 0 -saturation 0 -nomsgcolor -nomsgmodule -nokeepaspect -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-font-scale 1 /media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: new: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: launched: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: < MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Playing /media/gringo/videos/video.mp4.
GMLIB-Message: < Detected file format: QuickTime / MOV (libavformat)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_ID=0
GMLIB-Message: < [lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_ID=0
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AID_0_LANG=und
GMLIB-Message: < [lavf] stream 1: audio (aac), -aid 0, -alang und
GMLIB-Message: < Clip info:
GMLIB-Message: <  major_brand: mp42
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME0=major_brand
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE0=mp42
GMLIB-Message: <  minor_version: 0
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME1=minor_version
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE1=0
GMLIB-Message: <  compatible_brands: isommp42
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME2=compatible_brands
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE2=isommp42
GMLIB-Message: <  creation_time: 2014-03-22 04:45:23
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME3=creation_time
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE3=2014-03-22 04:45:23
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_N=4
GMLIB-Message: < Load subtitles in /media/gringo/videos/
GMLIB-Message: < ID_FILENAME=/media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: < ID_DEMUXER=lavfpref
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=H264
GMLIB-Message: Setting to minimum size so that mplayer has something to draw to
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=281136
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=640
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=360
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_FPS=30.000
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=1.7778
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=MP4A
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=96000
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_RATE=44100
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_NCH=2
GMLIB-Message: < ID_START_TIME=0.00
GMLIB-Message: < ID_LENGTH=4128.14
GMLIB-Message: < ID_SEEKABLE=1
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CHAPTERS=0
GMLIB-Message: < ERROR: Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i915.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < [vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
GMLIB-Message: < [VO_XV] Could not grab port 70.
GMLIB-Message: < [ass] auto-open
GMLIB-Message: < Selected video codec: H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 [libavcodec]
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_CODEC=ffh264
GMLIB-Message: < Selected audio codec: AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) [libavcodec]
GMLIB-Message: < AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 96.0 kbit/3.40% (ratio: 12000->352800)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=96000
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_RATE=44100
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_NCH=2
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew (0x7fd8149a6000)
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew (0x7fd8149a6000)
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew (0x7fd8149a6000)
GMLIB-Message: < AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew (0x7fd8149a6000)
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew (0x7fd8149a6000)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_CODEC=ffaac
GMLIB-Message: < [Mixer] No hardware mixing, inserting volume filter.
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew (0x7fd8149a6000)
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportmyyuew (0x7fd8149a6000)
GMLIB-Message: < Starting playback...
GMLIB-Message: < VIDEO:  640x360  30.000 fps  281.1 kbps (35.1 kB/s)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=1.7778
GMLIB-Message: < VO: [xv] 640x360 => 640x360 Planar YV12
GMLIB-Message: media_loaded: position=0.000 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to get value of property 'sub_source'.
GMLIB-Message: current size = 0 x 0
GMLIB-Message: Changing window size to 640 x 360 visible = true
GMLIB-Message: current size = 640 x 360
GMLIB-Message: Changing window size to 640 x 360 visible = true
GMLIB-Message: old: position=2.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=2.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=2.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=2.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=2.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=2.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=2.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=2.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=5.300 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=5.300 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=5.300 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=5.300 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=18.500 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=pause uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to disable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=20.200 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: old: position=22.100 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=22.100 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=stop uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: old: position=22.100 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=stop uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: new: position=22.100 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=stop uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: < Exiting... (Quit)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_EXIT=QUIT
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=22.100 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 898 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 899 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:32407): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 900 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: finished: position=22.100 length=4128.140 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/video.mp4
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GNOME MPlayer v1.0.9
gmtk v1.0.9
GTK 3.12.2
GLIB 2.42.0
GDA Enabled
```

Some obvious problems:

- it seems to be looking for options in the directory where the video
  its playing is located  it can't find an input.conf file in the
  user's home directory  it keeps "trying to enable screensaver" (20
  times in this brief test)  it keeps "trying to disable screensaver"
  (14 times in this brief test)  it keeps looking for a video called
  "filename" in the user directory where it was launched

The thing that makes mplayer the greatest media player are its keyboard shortcuts and the faultless control it usually gives over playback position and speed.

Current installed distribution: Ubuntu 15.04 running xfce4:
Current intsalled version:

```
gnome-mplayer
Versions:
1.0.9-3 (/var/lib/apt/lists/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_universe_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)

Reverse Depends:
  gnome-mplayer:i386,gnome-mplayer
  smtube,gnome-mplayer
  lubuntu-desktop,gnome-mplayer
  gnome-mplayer-dbg,gnome-mplayer 1.0.9-3
  gecko-mediaplayer,gnome-mplayer 1.0.7
Dependencies:
1.0.9-3 - libasound2 (2 1.0.16) libc6 (2 2.7) libcairo2 (2 1.2.4) libcurl3-gnutls (2 7.16.2) libdbus-1-3 (2 1.0.2) libdbus-glib-1-2 (2 0.78) libgda-5.0-4 (2 5.0.2) libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (2 2.22.0) libglib2.0-0 (2 2.35.9) libgmlib1 (2 1.0.7) libgmtk1 (2 1.0.7) libgpod4 (2 0.6.0) libgtk-3-0 (2 3.7.10) libmusicbrainz3-6 (2 3.0.2) libnautilus-extension1a (2 1:2.91) libnotify4 (2 0.7.0) libx11-6 (0 (null)) libxss1 (0 (null)) dconf-gsettings-backend (16 (null)) gsettings-backend (0 (null)) mplayer2 (16 (null)) mplayer (0 (null)) gecko-mediaplayer (0 (null)) gnome-icon-theme-symbolic (0 (null)) xdg-utils (0 (null)) gnome-mplayer:i386 (0 (null))
Provides:
1.0.9-3 -
Reverse Provides:
```

Comment: There's only so much time in the day, clearkimura. The error messages are relevant to the question and would be useful to anyone who is able to answer it.

Comment: Because I assume you pasted the output message that is *too long*, which cannot be fit all together within the question. Anyway, not sure if it is appropriate to paste the error log in the answer section, which is *not* an answer by itself.

Comment: Yes the question space was too small to accomodate my question. So I put the rest of it where I could, which was as an answer. The problem was not, as you say, that my question was too long, but that the space was too short. Are you able to help here at all, clearkimura?

Comment: I am running slightly older version of `gnome-mplayer` in 14.04. I have much less output messages, which are different than yours. I'd suggest to check again: whether the encoding of mp3 file is clean or damaged; and playing from local disk instead of external media and compare. P.S.: I think I found this post via "review queues", so I left the earlier comments as a reviewer.

Comment: I gave up on gnome-mplayer and installed mplayer. You have to run it from the command line but the keyboard controls work perfectly in the terminal. I'd forgotten that I'd been through a similar experience before using mplayer - accidentally installing gnome-mplayer, encountering some problem, then fishing out mplayer mplayer. The only problem is it seems you have to be a car mechanic to get mplayer working in a gui. Can't remember how I did it last time and the time before... so its terminal control for now. Thank you, clearkimura, for taking time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error log created when playing / stuttering an mp3:

```
GMLIB-Message: Running with GIO support
GMLIB-Message: Using audio device: 
GMLIB-Message: after init: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=0.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=
GMLIB-Message: failed to get mode: Error when getting information for file '/media/gringo/videos/options': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: opening options
GMLIB-Message: stat_result = -1
GMLIB-Message: is block false
GMLIB-Message: is character false
GMLIB-Message: is reg false
GMLIB-Message: is dir false
GMLIB-Message: playlist false
GMLIB-Message: embedded in window id 0x0
GMLIB-Message: playlist detection = false
GMLIB-Message: adding file:///media/gringo/videos/options to playlist (cancel = false)
GMLIB-Message: playlist detection = false
GMLIB-Message: adding file:///media/gringo/videos/filename to playlist (cancel = false)
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='com.gnome.mplayer'
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='org.gnome.SettingsDaemon'
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys'
GMLIB-Message: Proxy connections and Command connected
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2'
GMLIB-Message: Using match: type='signal',interface='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player'
GMLIB-Message: Proxy connections and Command connected ret = 2
GMLIB-Message: playing - file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: is playlist false
GMLIB-Message: old: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: new: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: setting up mplayer
GMLIB-Message: mplayer -channels 2 -af-add export=/tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb:512 -quiet -slave -noidle -noconsolecontrols -nostop-xscreensaver -identify -volume 100 -softvol -msglevel all=5 -osdlevel 0 -delay 0 -subdelay 0 -subpos 0 -sub-fuzziness 0 -wid 0x3400020 -brightness 0 -contrast 0 -hue 0 -saturation 0 -nomsgcolor -nomsgmodule -nokeepaspect -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-font-scale 1 /media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: launched: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: < MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Playing /media/gringo/videos/options.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/media/gringo/videos/options': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /media/gringo/videos/options.
GMLIB-Message: < Exiting... (End of file)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_EXIT=EOF
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 69 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 70 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 71 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: finished: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/options
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: playing - file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: is playlist false
GMLIB-Message: old: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: new: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: setting up mplayer
GMLIB-Message: mplayer -channels 2 -af-add export=/tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb:512 -quiet -slave -noidle -noconsolecontrols -nostop-xscreensaver -identify -volume 100 -softvol -msglevel all=5 -osdlevel 0 -delay 0 -subdelay 0 -subpos 0 -sub-fuzziness 0 -wid 0x3400020 -brightness 0 -contrast 0 -hue 0 -saturation 0 -nomsgcolor -nomsgmodule -nokeepaspect -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-font-scale 1 /media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: launched: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: < MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Playing /media/gringo/videos/filename.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/media/gringo/videos/filename': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /media/gringo/videos/filename.
GMLIB-Message: < Exiting... (End of file)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_EXIT=EOF
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 89 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 90 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 91 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: finished: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 89 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 91 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 90 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 89 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 91 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 90 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: old: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: new: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/filename
GMLIB-Message: opening playlist
GMLIB-Message: playlist detection = false
GMLIB-Message: adding file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3 to playlist (cancel = false)
GMLIB-Message: metadata retrieve from database is not valid, requesting it from media
GMLIB-Message: getting file metadata for /media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: mplayer -vo null -ao null -nomsgcolor -nomsgmodule -frames 0 -noidx -identify -nocache -noidle /media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: playing - file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: is playlist false
GMLIB-Message: old: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: new: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: setting up mplayer
GMLIB-Message: mplayer -channels 2 -af-add export=/tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb:512 -quiet -slave -noidle -noconsolecontrols -nostop-xscreensaver -identify -volume 100 -softvol -msglevel all=5 -osdlevel 0 -delay 0 -subdelay 0 -subpos 0 -sub-fuzziness 0 -wid 0x3400020 -brightness 0 -contrast 0 -hue 0 -saturation 0 -nomsgcolor -nomsgmodule -nokeepaspect -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-font-scale 1 /media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: launched: position=0.000 length=0.000 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: < MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /home/gringo/.mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.
GMLIB-Message: < Playing /media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3.
GMLIB-Message: < Detected file format: MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3) (libavformat)
GMLIB-Message: < [mp3 @ 0x7ff22b431b40]max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_ID=0
GMLIB-Message: < [lavf] stream 0: audio (mp3), -aid 0
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VIDEO_ID=0
GMLIB-Message: < ID_VID_0_NAME=
GMLIB-Message: < [lavf] stream 1: video (png), -vid 0,
GMLIB-Message: < Clip info:
GMLIB-Message: <  major_brand: mp42
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME0=major_brand
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE0=mp42
GMLIB-Message: <  minor_version: 0
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME1=minor_version
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE1=0
GMLIB-Message: <  compatible_brands: isommp42
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME2=compatible_brands
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE2=isommp42
GMLIB-Message: <  creation_time: 2014-03-22 04:45:23
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME3=creation_time
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE3=2014-03-22 04:45:23
GMLIB-Message: <  encoder: Lavf56.1.0
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME4=encoder
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE4=Lavf56.1.0
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CLIP_INFO_N=5
GMLIB-Message: < Load subtitles in /media/gringo/videos/
GMLIB-Message: < ID_FILENAME=/media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: < ID_DEMUXER=lavfpref
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=85
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=128000
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_RATE=44100
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_NCH=2
GMLIB-Message: < ID_START_TIME=0.00
GMLIB-Message: < ID_LENGTH=4128.18
GMLIB-Message: < ID_SEEKABLE=1
GMLIB-Message: < ID_CHAPTERS=0
GMLIB-Message: < Selected audio codec: MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III [mpg123]
GMLIB-Message: < AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 128.0 kbit/9.07% (ratio: 16000->176400)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=128000
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_RATE=44100
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_NCH=2
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb (0x7ff210e01000)
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb (0x7ff210e01000)
GMLIB-Message: < AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb (0x7ff210e01000)
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb (0x7ff210e01000)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_AUDIO_CODEC=mpg123
GMLIB-Message: < [Mixer] No hardware mixing, inserting volume filter.
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb (0x7ff210e01000)
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Exporting to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb
GMLIB-Message: < [export] Memory mapped to file: /tmp/mplayer-af_exportfnyykb (0x7ff210e01000)
GMLIB-Message: < Video: no video
GMLIB-Message: Running in audio only mode
GMLIB-Message: media_loaded: position=0.000 length=4128.180 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: < Starting playback...
GMLIB-Message: < Failed to set property 'sub_visibility' to '1'.
GMLIB-Message: old: position=39.400 length=4128.180 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=play uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: new: position=39.400 length=4128.180 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=stop uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: old: position=39.400 length=4128.180 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=stop uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: new: position=39.400 length=4128.180 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=running media=stop uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: < Exiting... (Quit)
GMLIB-Message: < ID_EXIT=QUIT
GMLIB-Message: completed: position=39.400 length=4128.180 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 884 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 885 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gnome-mplayer:2764): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 886 was not found when attempting to remove it
GMLIB-Message: finished: position=39.400 length=4128.180 start_time=0.000 run_time=0.000 volume=1.00 player=dead media=unknown uri=file:///media/gringo/videos/audio.mp3
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GMLIB-Message: trying to enable screensaver
GNOME MPlayer v1.0.9
gmtk v1.0.9
GTK 3.12.2
GLIB 2.42.0
GDA Enabled
```